Reading product attribute value for "All Store Views"?
Magento 2.4.6
Is there a way to read the value of a custom text field attribute value stored in the "All Store Views" scope? Currently I am using $product->getMyAttribute(); which returns me the value for the product from the store view I am in on frontend.
But in my case I need the value from "All store views" ... possible?
Thanks

...

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

...

$originalStoreId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

$this->storeManager->setCurrentStore(0);

$product = $this->productRepository->get('sku', false, 0);
$allStoreViewsValue = $product->getAttributeText('attribute_code');

$this->storeManager->setCurrentStore($originalStoreId);


Does not work, getting FALSE here

Made it work by calling $product->getMyAttribute(). Thanks!
